# Layout Not inflating while searching using Firebase DataBase kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, full-text-search

I am trying to create a feature that makes user search text on firebase database and if it exists i am inflating layout, for this i am using Kotlin and Firebase Database.
Even searching word is in firebase child it doesn't inflated layout like i mean giving results.
[Search activity layout not inflated img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COYVn.jpg)

[image: Firebase console img]

Search Activity :

```
class Search : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var bottomnav : BottomNavigationView

        private lateinit var commentRecyclerView: RecyclerView
        private lateinit var commentAdapter: Searchcommmentadapter
        private lateinit var firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase
        private lateinit var databaseReference: DatabaseReference
        private lateinit var adapter:Searchcommmentadapter
         private lateinit var commentList: List<Comment>
        private lateinit var searchview : SearchView
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_search)
            bottomnav = findViewById(R.id.bottomnavigation)
            commentRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv)
            searchview = findViewById(R.id.searchui)
            searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
            {
                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                    if (query != null) {
                        fetch(query)
                    }
                      return false
                }

                override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String?): Boolean {
                    if (query != null) {
                        fetch(query)
                    }
                    return false
                }

            })
            //commentRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,true)
            commentRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false)
            commentRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
                DividerItemDecoration(
                    this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
                )
            )
            val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            // linearLayoutManager.stackFromEnd = false
            // linearLayoutManager.reverseLayout = true
            commentRecyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager


            bottomnav.selectedItemId = R.id.csearch
            bottomnav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
                when(item.itemId){
                    R.id.home ->{
                        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0)
                        
                        true
                    }

                    R.id.cv ->{
                        startActivity(Intent(this, activity_for_playing_soma_videos::class.java))
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0)
                        
                        true
                    }

                    R.id.ch ->{
                        
                        startActivity(Intent(this, ForSomasunthaVideoActivity_CH::class.java))
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0)
                        
                         true
                    }

                    R.id.ctrend ->{
                        
                        startActivity(Intent(this, TrendingPosts::class.java))
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0)
                         true
                    }

                    R.id.csearch->{
                       // return true
                        
                        
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0)
                        true
                    }
                 
                }
                 false
            }
            
        }
         private fun fetch(query : String){
         firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
             val event = object : ValueEventListener {

                 override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                     commentList = ArrayList()
                     for(postsnap in snapshot.children) {
                         val database: FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()


                         val comment: Comment? = postsnap.getValue(Comment::class.java)
                         if (comment != null ) {


                             (commentList as ArrayList<Comment>).add(comment)

                         }
                     }

                     commentAdapter = Searchcommmentadapter(
                         this@Search,
                         commentList.asReversed() )
                     commentRecyclerView.adapter = commentAdapter

                 }

                 override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                 }

             }
             val quer: Query = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Comments").startAt(query).endAt("$query/uf8ff")
             quer.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(event)
         }

    }
```

Search Recyler View  Adapter:

```
class Searchcommmentadapter(private var context:Context, private var data: List<Comment>): RecyclerView.Adapter<Searchcommmentadapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Searchcommmentadapter.MyViewHolder {
        val row: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.searchui, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(row)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Searchcommmentadapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.lang.text = data[position].getPostLangBl()
        holder.commentTv.text = data[position].getComment()

        glidesh(position, holder.profile, holder.card)
        holder.shivprofile.text = data[position].getUserName()
        isLiked(data[position].getCommentKey().toString(), holder.willlike)
        nrLikes(holder.likecount, data[position].getCommentKey().toString())
    }

    private fun glidesh(position: Int, profile: ImageView, card: CardView) {

        Glide.with(context).load(data[position].getUri()).into(profile)
        if(data[position].getuEmail().toString() == "namashivayacompany@gmail.com"){
            card.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red))
        }
        else{
            card.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yellow))
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return data.size
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var commentTv: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_text)

        var sharepost: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_share_somam)
        var profile:ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile1)
        var shivprofile: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.namesh)

        var card: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lpshiv)
        var willlike: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar)
        var likecount: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.likecount)
        var lang: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.lang)

        init{
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(context, viewing_post_nama::class.java)
                val position: Int = adapterPosition
                intent.putExtra("Comment", data[position].getComment())
                intent.putExtra("UserName", data[position].getUserName())
                intent.putExtra("Uri", data[position].getUri())
                intent.putExtra("Postlang", data[position].getPostLangBl())
                context.startActivity(intent)

                sharepost.setOnClickListener{
                    val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                    val text = data[position].getComment() + "/n" + "  " + "Download Commenting App Now ! ! ! :) "
                    shareIntent.type = "text/plain"
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)
                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"SHARE COMMENT"))
                }

                profile.setOnClickListener{
                    createSnackbar("WELCOME ! ! !")
                }
            }

            val firebaseuser : FirebaseUser? = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
            willlike.setOnClickListener{
                if(willlike.tag.equals("like")){
                    if (firebaseuser != null) {
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("LikesOnly")
                            .child(data[position].getCommentKey().toString())
                            .child(firebaseuser.uid).setValue(true)
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if (firebaseuser != null) {
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("LikesOnly")
                            .child(data[position].getCommentKey().toString())
                            .child(firebaseuser.uid).removeValue()
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private fun createSnackbar(message: String){
            val ca: View = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shivaa)

            Snackbar.make(ca, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show()
        }

    }


    private fun isLiked(postId:String, imageview: ImageView ){
        val firebaseuser : FirebaseUser? = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        val database: FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val myRef: DatabaseReference = database.getReference("LikesOnly").child(postId)

        myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener
        {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (firebaseuser != null) {

                    if(snapshot.child(firebaseuser.uid).exists()){
                        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.liked)
                        imageview.setTag("liked")
                    }else{
                        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.disliked)
                        imageview.setTag("like")

                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }

        })

    }

    private fun nrLikes(likes : TextView,  postId : String){
        val database: FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val myRef: DatabaseReference = database.getReference("LikesOnly").child(postId)

        myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                likes.text = snapshot.childrenCount.toString() + " " + "Likes"

            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }

        })

    }

}
```

I don't know what i did wrong, but it doesn't inflating layout.

Comment: There are over 250 lines of code in your question, many of them likely unrelated to the problem. While there's always a chance somebody spots the problem, that chance goes up drastically if your reduce the problem to a [**minimal** repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful) and debug it locally. So after reproducing the problem in minimal code, Iset a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line. Which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: If you're new to debugging Android code, the Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @FrankvanPuffelen , In the fetch function only I got issues. when I search text in search view firebase needs to sort the value  and inflate layout according to that value. so that i think this issue is related to fetch function and search adapter. and sorry for lot of lines. I did that because I thought if I add my code they can understand my issue. now I could understand, sorry.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Hi , What i expected : Searching values in firebase database child if the value is there inflate value and display search related child values.        The issue : layout not inflated even I have same search value in firebase database.                     And i didn't got any error in log and any exception . Thanks for your comment.